# MySQL INNER JOIN on same table not working

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
nID | tID | rID | code | name
------------------------------
10  | 6   | 74  | 4254 | Argos
11  | 7   | 74  | 4254 | Okrash
12  | 8   | 74  | 4254 | Pyro
13  | 8   | 0   | 4254 | Maja
14  | 9   | 74  | 4254 | Caiu
15  | 10  | 74  | 4254 | Sobre
16  | 10  | 0   | 4254 | Inye
```

This is how I need the result:

```
nID | name
-------------
10  | Argos
11  | Okrash
13  | Maja
14  | Caiu
16  | Inye
```

Below is the MySQL query I am using. Obviously it's not working (It returns no output). I also need nID and name as 2 columns only in the output. Can't figure it out.

```
SELECT a.nID, a.name, b.nID, b.name FROM codeTable AS a
INNER JOIN codeTable AS b
ON a.rID = b.rID
WHERE a.rID='74' AND a.code='4254' AND a.tID NOT IN (10, 8)
AND b.rID='0' AND b.code='4254' AND b.tID IN (10, 8)
```

Comment: _Obviously it's not working_ isn't obvious outside your head :) What's the output?

Comment: What is the logic you're applying to get that output (in plain english)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you doing a join for a simple selection query?

```
SELECT ct.nID, ct.name, ct.nID, ct.name
FROM codeTable ct
WHERE (ct.rID = '74' AND ct.code = '4254' AND ct.tID NOT IN (10, 8)) or
      (ct.rID = '0' AND ct.code = '4254' AND ct.tID IN (10, 8));
```

If your `id`s and `code`s are numbers, then don't use the single quotes.  Reserve them for string (and date) constants.

The reason your query is returning no rows is because the `join` condition conflicts with the `where` clause.  The `join` condition specifies tht the `rID`s are the same for `a` and `b`.  The `where` clause is looking for two different values (`a.rID = '74' and b.rid = '0').

Comment: Hmmm... I think your solution sounds about right. Why am I overcomplicating this... I think I tried something similar before. I must have forgotten to use OR. Thanks.